Телефон андроид постоянно ломится на непонятный сайт, обнаружено с помощью adguard
Разные приложения постоянно просят доступ к
ire-oneid.shalltry.com
Что это и как победить?
Телефон Tecno SPARK 20 Pro
Android 13
HiOS V13.5.0

